# How to say They came, they saw, they conquered in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin, gaius-iulius-caesar

I would like to translate the famous Julius Caesar quote into the third person plural:

> They Came, They Saw, They Conqurered.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to sound archaic or poetic, say "Venere, videre, vicere.". If you do not, say "Venerunt, viderunt, vicerunt.". Latin, namely, has two endings for perfect 3rd person plural, "-ere" and "-erunt", "-ere" being poetic and archaic.

Comment: I'd quibble slightly with calling '-ere' archaic or poetic. Granted it's more often used in poetry (metrical flexibility) but it's still reasonably common in Classical prose. It's worth noting that the colloquial form was '-ĕrunt'; Kennedy §15 suggests that '-ērunt' was a compromise between that and '-ēre'.